# How can I grab a running browser process and get the current active url in electron JS?

Tags: electron

I am trying to make a desktop work monitoring app. I need to find out the URL of the current tab while a user is using the browser. I chose Electron js for implementation, but can't seem to find a way to fulfill my requirement.
Does anyone know how to do this in electron js?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which OS, which web browser?

Comment: I wished to make the app cross-platform and planned to get active process and if its a browser process(of any browser type) then get the current active url.